# Why does order of migrations matter in Heroku Postgres but not local Postgres database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I was having a hell of a time earlier trying to figure out why Heroku couldn't run my migrations. It kept complaining that a reference did not exist.

For my first migration, I referenced a table that hadn't been created yet using a foreign key. In order to solve this problem, I had to arbitrarily modify the timestamps of the migration files so that no table would be created before a table it depends on (references).

Amazingly, this solved the problem with running the migrations on Heroku and they eventually ran without error. Also, the migrations would run perfectly on my development machine, even with the tables that have dependencies being created before the referenced tables exist.

`Why did it work on my local database and not on the Heroku database? Is there something I can do next time this happens? It seems really ridiculous to have to always create migrations in order of their dependency in order to please Heroku. I must be missing something, no?`

Comment: It should fail in your local environment too. You probably played around with it, creating/deleting migrations (without rollbacking), when you uploaded to Heroku all the intermediate playing around didn't exists in the db on Heroku.

Comment: Connect to your local Postgres database and attempt to create a foreign key to a table that doesn't exist ... I think you will find it doesn't like it.